# magento 2 configurable product image does not update completely

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, image

I have a configurable product (sub-product A,B and C) with each assigned with different color image gallery.

I expected the image gallery will auto switch according to which color is selected in frontend. But to find that only the first image in a color specified gallery can display.

The rest in the each gallery are ignored. I want to display all images specified for child when they are selected in store front

Does anyone notice about this issue or have any work around for it? thanks.

Comment: Are you want to display all product images of child when they selected?

Comment: Yes, I want to display all images specified for child when they are selected in store front

Comment: Any update on this? Sitting with same issue, configurable product only shows images assigned to its' own gallery but nothing of the simple products associated with it.

Even when I choose a product via swatch the image doesn't change.